# AngularJS pass URL in attribute to isolated scope of directive - unexpected token ':'

Tags: javascript, angularjs, binding, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm fairly new to AngularJS and just started using it a few days ago, so forgive me if the question itself is incorrect.

The problem I ran into is that I'd like to pass a URL parameter via attribute to the isolated scope of my directive, but at the `:` part in `http://` it gives me an error, saying `Syntax Error: Token ':' is an unexpected token at column 5 of the expression [http://`...

The HTML part of the directive (where I "call" it) is something like this:

```
<myDirective datasource="http://url"></myDirective>
```

And I bind(?) it to the isolated scope like this:

```
scope: {
    dataSource: '=datasource'
}
```

If the value of the attribute contains only simple characters, it works. How can I solve this?

Thanks.

Comment: wrap url inside single quote will work`<myDirective datasource="`http://url`"></myDirective>`

Comment: can u share how to create this directive

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your case angular is trying to evaluating value of `datasource` attribute. Because you mention `=` i.e. two way binding for variable.

If you wrap URL inside `'` (single quote) will solve your problem. because the mentioned value will directly binded to directive isolated scope variable.

**Markup**

```
<my-directive datasource="'http://url'"></my-directive>
```

Comment: Since I need two-way binding for other reasons, this is the answer I needed.

Comment: what about if in the link I have variables from scope? like `<my-directive link="#/orders/{{vm.order.id}}"></my-directive>
`

Comment: it would be `<my-directive link="'#/orders/' + vm.order.id "></my-directive>`

Answer (score 6):

Dont use '=' in directive instead use @ because you are passing normal string.

```
scope: {
    dataSource: '@datasource'
}
```

Comment: One should really use `=` when binding to a variable and `@` for literal strings. Anything else would be confusing.

Comment: Since I need two-way binding for other reasons, I accepted another answer. But what you say is very useful and thank you for that. :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to to have two-way data binding `'='` you have to bind it with a scope variable or pass a quoted string:

```
<myDirective datasource="'http://url'"></myDirective>
```

Answer (score 1):

Angular tries to use your value as a variable name.

From [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes): "The object hash is used to set up two-way binding (using '=') or one-way binding (using '@') between the parent scope and the isolate scope. There is also '&' to bind to parent scope expressions."

You should use:

```
scope: {
    dataSource: '@datasource'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To define a isolate scope, just put '@' into scope definition and use the atribute name in your directive.

```
.directive('ggThumbnail', function()
{
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            thumbnailSrc: '@',
            thumbnailWidth: '@',
            thumbnailHeight: '@'
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl)
        {
            ctrl.init(element);

            attrs.$observe('thumbnailSrc', function()
            {
                if (attrs.thumbnailSrc)
                {
                    ctrl.prepareImage();
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: can u share how to create this directive